# Excel VBA with SAP GUI 7.40 - SAP.Functions not working

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I have a Excel VBA which connects to SAP GUI, pulls some data and does some processing on it. It was working fine with **SAP GUI 7.20** But it stopped working when I installed **SAP GUI 7.40**.

My code is as below :

```
Dim obBAPICall As Object

Set obBAPICall = CreateObject("SAP.Functions")
```

I get following error :

> Run-time error '-2147024770 (8007007e)':
>
> Automation error 
> The specified module could not be found.
> [image]

I've already gone through some weblinks and I believe I've all the required references. (In fact, I've added many more in order to troubleshoot the problem).

[image]

My SAP GUI version is :

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

---

Edit : Following code does not have any problem :

```
Set SAPguiApp = CreateObject("Sapgui.ScriptingCtrl.1")
```

Comment: You really shouldn't need to add references since you are creating the `SAP.Functions` object using late binding. That doesn't answer you question though :(  I just pulled up a very old workbook where I had used `sap.functions` as a POC and ran into all sorts of issues with version 730, although different from yours. I tried a second sheet where I used `sap.bapi.1` to interact with BAPIs in R/3 and it worked fine. I assume it's a missing library or something on the SAP install.

Comment: Hey, thanks mate. Appreciate your help. That's why I thought too. But then I since it stopped working, I started with the troubleshooting various things one by one. Adding references is one of them. In my earlier version (I mean, with SAP GUI 7.2, I had not added any reference specifically.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it ! The problem was with the latest MS office product (and not with SAP GUI 7.40). The IT guys had rolled out some updates in MS Office and it was creating a problem. I restored MS Office and it is working fine now.